# How to make text dynamically fit inside TextEditor frame?

Tags: swiftui

I want to give the TextEditor a particular frame, say, 200x200 and while I type I want for text to dynamically shrink in size when the line gets bigger than 200 so in the end all the text stays on screen without scrolling.

Basically the text just zooms in and out insize the frame to fit it.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: With your requirement, your text font needs to be decreased when the text length increases. It theoretically leads to a weird font size.

Comment: A single-line `TextField` will work this way if you apply `.minimumScaleFactor(0.01)` to it. However, it doesn't work for a multi-line (scrolling) `TextField` or a `TextEditor`, unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

SwiftUI doesn't have a built-in way to achieve dynamic text size within a fixed-size TextEditor, we can combine several techniques to create a similar effect, here's an example:

```
struct DynamicTextSizeTextView: UIViewRepresentable {
  @Binding var text: String

  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
    let textView = UITextView()
    textView.delegate = context.coordinator
    textView.text = text
    return textView
  }

  func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
    uiView.text = text
    calculateFontSize(for: uiView)
  }

  func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
  }

  class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
    let parent: DynamicTextSizeTextView

    init(_ parent: DynamicTextSizeTextView) {
      self.parent = parent
    }

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
      calculateFontSize(for: textView)
    }

    func calculateFontSize(for textView: UITextView) {
      guard let attributedText = textView.attributedText,
            let fittingSize = textView.sizeThatFits(textView.frame.size) else { return }

      var newFontSize = textView.font?.pointSize ?? 16.0
      let idealLineHeight = fittingSize.height / CGFloat(textView.lineCount)

      while newFontSize > 8.0 && idealLineHeight > textView.font?.lineHeight ?? 16.0 {
        newFontSize -= 1.0
        attributedText.enumerateAttribute(.font, in: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedText.length), options: []) { value, range, stop in
          if let font = value as? UIFont {
            let newFont = font.withSize(newFontSize)
            attributedText.removeAttribute(.font, range: range)
            attributedText.addAttribute(.font, value: newFont, range: range)
          }
        }
      }
      textView.attributedText = attributedText
    }
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
struct MyView: View {
  @State private var text = ""

  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geo in
      DynamicTextSizeTextView(text: $text)
        .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: 200)
        .clipped()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the code doesn't compile